# php echo variable stored in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm trying to find out how I can echo the variable name that is stored in my mysql database.
For example:

In the field 'variable' of a table I have stored:

```
$target["year"]
```

PHP code:

```
$target["year"]="2013";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))    
{ 
    echo $row['variable']; // Output should be 2013
}
```

I read the article variables variable on php.net but I can't find the solution for my problem

Comment: Then store the value in the database ;) in the field `variable` then you have the output `2013`.

Comment: If you look at your database directly, do you see "2013" in the `variable` column for the database? If not, you need to look at how you're inserting your data to the database. It might be helpful for us to see your code for inserting to the DB as well...

Comment: Storing the name of a variable in your database table (instead of storing the value) seems like a confusing way to do things.

Comment: The purpose is to controlling a little bit of my php code with the variable stored in the db.

Comment: You can probably get want you want by using `eval`, but I strongly urge you to reconsider your structure. The data stored in your database should not be used as code.

Comment: Could you clarify a little better what you need, with a little better example? Maybe you need something like this: `$a="b"; $b=1; echo $$a; //will output 1`? Please explain a little better.

Comment: You should describe exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish, because I can pretty much guarantee there's a better way to do it.